# Google Maps using PHP/PostGreSQL - map not loading

Tags: php, javascript, xml, google-maps

I'm trying to produce a map with multiple markers using XML values which are produced using a PHP file I have written. I can successfully print out XML values from my PostGreSQL database onto a 'markers.php' page.

However, when I try and load the data into a Google Maps map the map itself doesn't show or any of the markers. The canvas in which the map is placed doesn't appear either.

Could anyone identify a problem with my script? The PHP side of things work perfectly I'm just looking for a solution which will load the map and the multiple markers with lat/lng values taken from the database. Please see the relevant files below.

**Markers.php**

```
session_start();
$username = $_SESSION['nickname']; 

function parseToXml($htmlStr)
{
    $xmlStr=str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('>','&gt;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace('"','&quot;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr); 
    $xmlStr=str_replace("&",'&amp;',$xmlStr); 
    return $xmlStr; 
}

$conn = pg_connect("dbconnectionstring");   

if(!conn){
    die ("Not connected : " . pg_last_error());
}

/*USE $username VARIABLE TO GET THE U_ID WHICH CORRESPONDS TO THE OWNER COLUMN IN RECORDS*/
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username'";
$sqlres = pg_query($sql);
$sqlassoc = pg_fetch_assoc($sqlres);
$owner = $sqlassoc['u_id'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM records WHERE owner='$owner'";
$result = pg_query($query);
if(!$result){
    die('Invalid query : ' . pg_last_error());
}

header("Content-type: text/xml");

echo '<markers>';

while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($result)){

    echo '<marker ';
    echo 'name="' . parseToXML($row['name']) . '" '; 
    echo 'description="' . parseToXML($row['description']) . '" ';
    echo 'latitude="' .parseToXML($row['latitude']) . '" ';
    echo 'longitude="' .parseToXML($row['longitude']) . '" ';
    echo 'project="' .parseToXML($row['project']) . '" ';
    echo '/>';
}

echo '</markers>';
```

This script works perfectly and produces the XML appropriately.

**Map.php** - which contains the javascript

```
      function load(){
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
         center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.4129, -4.0774),
        zoom: 13,
        mayTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    /*markers.php file in same directory as map.php*/
    downloadUrl("markers.php", function(data){
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("description");
        var project = markers[i].getAttribute("project");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("latitude")),
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("longitude")));
        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br />" + "<b>" + description + "</b> <br />" + project;
        var iconBase = 'http://users.aber.ac.uk/dwd/mfb/images';
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: iconBase + 'map_icon.png'
        });
        bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
    }
});

   }

function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
});

}

function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
    var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
        new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
        new XMLHttpRequest;

    request.onreadstatechange = function() {
        if(request.readyState == 4) {
            request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
            callback(request, request.status);
            }
        };

  request.open('GET', url, true);
  request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {}
```

This code is taken from the Google Maps with PHP/MySQL tutorial and yet I can't see to get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: `mayTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP` should be `mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP`.   I'm assuming you have a DIV for the map already and you are including the google maps api?

Comment: will try this out and your assumptions are correct.

Comment: correct the spelling error but still no luck :(

Comment: I realised I had changed the id of my div from "map-canvas" to "map" and hadn't made the CSS modifications. To quote Homer Simpson 'D'oh!!'